# XHTML 5 from Play 2.2.x using Java

Tags: java, html, xhtml, playframework-2.0

How do I set the content type to `application/xhtml+xml` globally and not only on a `Result` level? (In a Play Framework **Java** Project)

My `xhtml5` page looks like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="de" lang="de">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
      </head>
      <body></body>
    </html>
```

The `Result` is generated by `return ok(index.render())`.

If the content type is not set via `response().setContentType("application/xhtml+xml")` the play framework will serve `text/html` which is not correct.

Comment: You mean you want to set all pages to application/xhtml+xml automatically without having to do it for each file manually?

Comment: Yes, I want to set it as default for all served pages.